# What is best practice to represent data by Scala case classes

Tags: scala, class, case-class

For exmaple,  in scope of web service, case classes are used for storing and returning data from REST API.

Sometimes for different endpoint there is a need of similar classes with slight differences (for example only one field is different.)

for example:

```
case class Example (id: Int, value:Int)
case class ExampleWithName (id: Int, value:Int, name:String)
case class ExampleWithNameAndDate (id: Int, value:Int, name:String,createdOn:LocalDate)
```

would like to ask is the sollution to create new case class for each return type is the best, or there is better one, because there appears a lot similar code/classes.

Comment: You could use a single `case class` and supply default values for the missing constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1) Copypaste

```
case class Example (id: Int, value:Int)
case class ExampleWithName (id: Int, value:Int, name:String)
```

pros and cons: we all know them :)

2) Optional values

```
case class ExampleWithName (id: Int, value:Int, name: Option[String])
```

pros: no duplication

cons: if in a particular usecase you expect the name to be present it is not compile-time checked. And if you don't need the name you still have redundant noisy field.

3) Aggregation

```
case class Example (id: Int, value:Int)
case class ExampleWithName (example: Example, name:String)
```

pros: no flaws from previous approaches

cons: may require additional efforts to marshal this nested structure into a flat json.

Comment: So does not looks like that there is some kind of "best practice" and probably "copypaste" is the best, due to easiest maintain and clear implementation. In my opinion.

Comment: I think that the first approach is the best for prototyping. Then after the domain model has been clarified and stabilized I'd refactor it into the third.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you gonna use these case classes. From your example, one way you can do it is to declare those optional fields as Option.

```
case class Example(id: Int, value: Int, name: Option[String], createdOn: Option[LocalDate])
```